# Sphinx full text search filtered by id list

Tags: php, full-text-search, sphinx

I am thinking about implementing [Sphinx](http://www.sphinxsearch.com) in a project.

However I can't find if its posible to search in a large predefined range.

Let's say the user filters on all sorts of filter parameters (returning 10.000 records / id's), and also a text search. Can I let Sphinx do the (full)text search, limiting it to the records from the previous mysql search.

I know that you kan give [filter conditions](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-sphinxsearch/) to Sphinx, (eg. $sphinx->SetFilter( 'model', array( 3 ) );). But is it possible to give a huge array as filter (without making it slow)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible, easier in SphinxQL, but works in the API too, something like

```
$sphinx->setSelect("*,IN(id,2,3,4,5,6,7,8) as myint");
$sphinx->setFilter('myint',array(1));
```

Not sure about performance, wont be great.

Comment: I tried this, using: `'*,IN(id,'.implode(',',range(1,100000)).') as myint';` the performance went down from 0.003 sec to 0.024 sec, while running on my (slow) mac mini. I think this is totally acceptable.

Comment: excellent! Have only used it on short lists, had no idea how would work on a long list. Good to know